# How do I count the number of open buffers / files in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, lisp

Every now and then, I accidentally hit C-x C-c in Emacs when I'm intending to just hit C-x or C-c. This, of course, closes all open frames and buffers with no confirmation. I know that I can make Emacs prompt "Are you sure you want to exit?", but I don't want to do that all the time, which would get annoying. I just want it to do it when there are more than N files (or buffers) open.

So I'd like to bind C-x C-c to a function along the lines of:

```
(if (< number of open buffers n)
    (save-buffers-kill-emacs)
    (are-you-sure))
```

But I can't figure out how to get the number of open buffers (or the number of open frames, or the number of open files, etc).

Answer (score 9):

This is what I use:

```
(defun count-buffers (&optional display-anyway)
  "Display or return the number of buffers."
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf-count (length (buffer-list))))
    (if (or (interactive-p) display-anyway)
    (message "%d buffers in this Emacs" buf-count)) buf-count))
```

I stole it <del>, but can't remember from where</del>. from [John Sturdy](http://www.cb1.com/~john), who sounds like a fascinating fellow; it's available from [his website](http://www.cb1.com/~john/computing/emacs/lisp/startup/buffer-misc.el).

Answer (score 4):

Also, you can consider using desktop-mode, which will automatically restore your buffers when you start Emacs again. Just add

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

to your `.emacs`.
See [GNU Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Saving-Emacs-Sessions.html) or [Emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeskTop).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the title question is simply `(length (buffer-list)`.

The built-in variable `kill-emacs-query-functions` can be customized to prompt the user.

Here's an example that exits if a small number of buffers are open or prompts otherwise. Add it to your `custom-set-variables` expression in your `init.el`.

```lisp
 '(kill-emacs-query-functions
   '((lambda nil
       "Kill Emacs if 16 or fewer buffers open or user says yes."
       (if
           (> (length (buffer-list)) 16)
           (yes-or-no-p "Kill Emacs? ")
         t))))
```

You can count open frames with `(length (frame-list))`.